# How do in install radare2 from source offline?

Tags: radare2

Hi I downloaded radare2 source code and ran `./sys/install.sh`

However it actually failed due to connection time out to `codeload.github.com` while under terminal prints "ar: creating libr_winkd.a".

I tried to google and search offline install method but haven't found any clue.

Thus I would like to ask how I should avoid this, what kind of dependency I should install in order to install radare2 offline??

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the install.sh you ran is [this one](https://github.com/radareorg/radare2/blob/master/sys/install.sh).

If you look at the script, you will see that it includes the following:

```
# update
if [ "$1" != "--without-pull" ]; then
    if [ -d .git ]; then
        git branch | grep "^\* master" > /dev/null
        if [ $? = 0 ]; then
            echo "WARNING: Updating from remote repository"
            # Attempt to update from an existing remote
            UPSTREAM_REMOTE=$(git remote -v | grep 'radareorg/radare2 (fetch)' | cut -f1 | head -n1)
            if [ -n "$UPSTREAM_REMOTE" ]; then
                git pull "$UPSTREAM_REMOTE" master
            else
                git pull https://github.com/radareorg/radare2 master
            fi
        fi
    fi
else
    export WITHOUT_PULL=1
    shift
fi
```

This appears to be what is causing the script to talk to Github.

One possible solution would be to add a `--without-pull` option to the script's arguments.  But I suspect that that won't work.  (It looks to me like the earlier options processing will "consume" the `--without-pull` ...)

Another possible solution would be to remove the above lines and replace them with:

```
export WITHOUT_PULL=1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Let me try first...... however, a little bit worry of skipping these lines may cause any other problems??

Comment: Well you should be able to read the code and understand what they do.  The point is that since you are running the install while offline it will be >impossible< to pull updates from Github.  (That's what offline means ...)

Comment: Hi I tried, failed again in the same place T T

Comment: So ... what did you try?  Adding the option or removing the code?  (Did you read where I said "I suspect that won't work" ?)

Comment: remove the if else, simply leave `export WITHOUT_PULL=1`

Comment: Hmmm ... OK ... add `set -x` near the start of the script and run it again to see what command is actually failing.

Comment: it says 
`ar: creating libr_winkd.a
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:07 --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed connect to codeload.github.com:443; Connection timed out
gmake[1]: *** [capstone-4.0.2.tar.gz] Error 7
gmake: *** [all] Error 2
+ exit 1`